# Divide HTML content into fixed size divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a long scrollable HTML content with includes text and images.
i need to divide and insert this content in to fixed size(A4 size) divs. how this is possible with javascript or jQuery?[image]

```html
<div class="content">
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
        
<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>
        
<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
</div>
<div>
<!-- pages should be created in here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. It is possible by writing jQuery code. please show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS so we can see how the page is built. With that we can help, but you'd probably be able to do it with CSS (if you can edit your CSS)

Comment: If you're trying to get everything to fit on an A4 for printing purposes, have a look at the page-break css rules to force each div onto a new page.

Comment: i just added the html. content in the "content" class has to be inserted as pages.

Comment: You may have to restructure your HTML

Answer (score 1):

It isn't.  An HTML document is not a Microsoft Word document.  The HTML has to accommodate many different browsers on many different platforms.  At the end of the day, HTML is designed to flow into one large rectangular shape and be viewed on-screen no matter where it's opened.

You're attempting to force a printing standard (A4 size) on a technology that is not designed for it.  CSS has some capabilities to add page breaks, but whether or not a browser interprets them as appropriately as a word processor would is hit-or-miss.  You could write all the Javascript in the world to do this "virtual" page break on browser "A", and get it looking and printing perfectly, and have it completely fall apart on browser "B".  HTML wasn't designed for page-at-a-time viewing.

Answer (score -1):

I've been looking for the solution and I found a link to w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Here they say to use page-break-after, to break a page where you want, with the mediaquery print, in te example they use the footer to break the page but I think that you can create a class and put this class where you want to be the page broke.

Example:

```
@media print {.breakpoint {page-break-after: always;}}
```

Then set the class "Breakpoint" where you want the content to be broke.

Hope this helps :)